# IE 10 poster image is overridden by source in video tag

Tags: html

I have a video tag with a poster image of png type and i have a source video but in IE10 source video frame is overriding the poster image.

see the sample code. i have set preload to none to avoid the  IE 9 issue, but anyone can suggest whats the issue with IE10. Do i need to give content type?

```
    <video width="100%" height="100%" poster="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" preload="none" controls="">
       <source src="http//example.mp4">
   </video>
```

Comment: This is probably only happening when you preview files locally.  Chances are it won't be an issue when you publish your site on the web.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it with all browsers using CSS

HTML:

```
<div class="video-wrapper">
    <video width="100%" height="100%" poster="path/your-image.jpg" preload="none" id="videoPlayer">
        <source src="http//example.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.video-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(path/your-image.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}

#index-video {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    z-index: -100;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: url(path/your-image.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: i am adding my videos dynamically so how can i change dynamically in the css

Comment: In that case you can add inline style for background dynamically with each video element.